# Configuring Zendesk notifications for follow-ups

Tags: zendesk

When I create follow-up for a closed ticket and send a public comment, the user receives a `Received request` notification, instead of `Comment Update` notification.

I assume the problem is in the conditions. I'm sending screenshots of how both notifications are set.

How to update the conditions to send a `Comment Update` notification instead `Received request` notification when an agent sends a public comment via a follow-up?

[image: Received request notification]
[image: Comment update notification]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to disable triggering the *received request* trigger, add the following condition to the *received request* trigger:

`Update via is not closed ticket`

After saving, clone the *received request* trigger and change the previous condition in the cloned trigger to

`Update via is closed ticket`

This cloned trigger is what you use to notify the end user of an update to a follow up ticket. However, the `Ticket is created` condition has to remain because technically this is a new ticket, not an update. You can change the title and notification content as you wish.

Comment: Perfect, it works. The follow-ups don't create "request received" notification and cloning "received request" notification, updating, "Updated via" condition, and changing the email body to inform customer about the new message worked.